# Memory leak with new and delete

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I tried to modify some previous code but find that the memory the program used keep increasing as it runs. So there might be a memory leak. The major part of my code contains the following loop

```
CEnergymulti* ener;
double potential;
double pottemp;

potential=0.0;
pottemp=0.0;

for(int i=0;i<nbin;i++)
{
 ener = new CEnergymulti(np1,molfnames1,idiel);
  pottemp=ener->calculatePot(ener->m_mols);
  potential+=pottemp;
 delete ener;
}
```

where 'CEnergymulti' is a class. I suspect the repeated use of new and delete may cause the memory leak problem, since if I just perform a single run for the code within the loop, I didn't see increase in memory during running. If it is indeed the problem with new and delete, how can I correct this? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see a memory leak. How are you sure you're leaking memory? Run something like `valgrind` on your code.

Comment: Maybe `CEnergymulti`'s destructor doesn't completely free its memory. Maybe `calculatePot` leaks memory. Tushar's suggestion is great: `valgrind` is an ideal tool.

Comment: In this particular piece of code there is no memory leak as you are allocating in the loop and deallocating in the loop as well.. so whatever memory gets allocated is freed before the next iteration. nneonneo's right may be you need to check calculatePort part.

Answer (score 1):

There is no memory leak in the code you show(*Unless there is a badly implemented destructor for `CEnergymulti`*)But there is no compelling reason to use dynamically allocated object to begin with. Why not simply use:

```
CEnergymulti obj;
pottemp=obj.calculatePot(obj.m_mols);
potential+=pottemp;
```

Drop the uneeded `new` and `delete` and you don't have to bother about manual memory mangement anymore.

Comment: Can't say that for sure! We can't see all the code, and there's plenty of unseen code that could leak.